# Disabling a user from using the back button once they have navigated to a new page in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a website that has an exit button. Once the exit button is clicked, I need to navigate away from my current page to Google AND I need it so that my back button can't be pressed to find my webpage. How would I do this using Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this piece of code to prevent going back:

`window.onbeforeunload = () => { return "You cannot propagate back."; };`